# How to fix: 'Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener...' on this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault, passive-event-listeners

Chrome gives me this error on console:

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener
>   due to target being treated as passive. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312

The part on code is this (specially this part 'event.preventDefault();'):

```
/**
             * Mouse wheel handler.
             * @param {Object} event
             */
            function wheel(event) {

                if (!initDone) {
                    init();
                }

                var target = event.target;
                var overflowing = overflowingAncestor(target);

                // use default if there's no overflowing
                // element or default action is prevented
                if (!overflowing || event.defaultPrevented ||
                    isNodeName(activeElement, "embed") ||
                   (isNodeName(target, "embed") && /\.pdf/i.test(target.src))) {
                    return true;
                }

                var deltaX = event.wheelDeltaX || 0;
                var deltaY = event.wheelDeltaY || 0;

                // use wheelDelta if deltaX/Y is not available
                if (!deltaX && !deltaY) {
                    deltaY = event.wheelDelta || 0;
                }

                // check if it's a touchpad scroll that should be ignored
                if (!options.touchpadSupport && isTouchpad(deltaY)) {
                    return true;
                }

                // scale by step size
                // delta is 120 most of the time
                // synaptics seems to send 1 sometimes
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > 1.2) {
                    deltaX *= options.stepSize / 120;
                }
                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > 1.2) {
                    deltaY *= options.stepSize / 120;
                }

                scrollArray(overflowing, -deltaX, -deltaY);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
```

How can i fix this problem in the code above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript, jQuery is not my territory, can i fix it by replacing:
event.preventDefault();

by:
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
}, {
  passive: false
});

Comment: Yes, that will solve it. But have a look at the linked answer, it would be a good thing to also check if the browser supports that feature. Edit - of course `e` and `event` in your example should be the same parameter.